# Unset multiple php variable variables

Tags: php, variables, variable-variables

I have a whole grip of variable variables that I create in a while loop from a MySQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM fruit_table";
$result = mysql_query($result);

//for sake of argument, well say this creates 3 rows to loop through.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $var = $row[1];
 $$var = $row[2];
}
```

Now we'll assume this has created: $orange = 'orange', $apple = 'red', $banana = 'yellow'. This function is going to loop back around multiple times, but I need all of the variables unset/nulled before it runs again. The variable names may be different each time based on the query that's run.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
unset($var);
unset($$var);
```

How do I go about looping though multiple variable names and unsetting all of them? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is refactoring out the variable variables realistic?  Just call `_fetch_assoc` instead of `_fetch_array` to get yourself a nice happy associative array.  Variable variables are a code smell.  Also ...

Comment: I think if you used an array you would have less hassle. There is no reason in PHP, except for %0.1 of cases where variable variables are really necessary. Just use arrays and save a lot of time on debugging ;)

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to save the variable names that you created into an array, then unset all of them:

```
$created_vars = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $var = $row[1];
    $created_vars[] = $var;
    $$var = $row[2];
}

foreach( $created_vars as $var) {
    unset( $$var);
}
```

That being said, you should consider abandoning variable-variables, and just use an array.